# I don't manage to make the ng-hide directive work on Angular 7

Tags: angular

This problem has been treated abundantly and i know there are a tremendous amount of threads concerning this issue, because i read them. However, i'm currently bunching my head on the same rock since yesterday, and the rock is called ng-hide directive. I am working with angular 7, so the last version, but i don't think that any change have occurred concerning this particular directive.

Please consider the following code :

```
export class PlanetComponent implements OnInit {

  planet = 'earth'

  switcherPlanet() : void {
    if(this.planet == 'earth'){
      this.planet = 'venus'
    }
    else if(this.planet == 'venus'){
      this.planet = 'earth'
    }
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

And this one :

```
<div>
  <span ng-hide = 'planet!=="earth"'>
     Hello Earth
  </span>
  <br>
  <span ng-hide = 'planet!=="venus"' >
    Hello Venus
  </span>
  <button (click)="switcherPlanet()"> Switch </button>
</div>
```

As you can see, this code is not accomplishing something out of this world. The idea is that if you click on the button, it should  switch from a div to an another using the ng-hide directive.

The problem is that this seemingly trivial operation is not working as expected : both the two elements will never hide and still remain visible after the click. I should be dumb, but what is the matter with it? Thank you very much for reading it and even more if you take the time to answer.

Comment: ng-hide don't exist in Angular (is AngularJs), you can use *ngIf or [hidden] or [style.display]

Comment: I think you are looking for `*ngIf="planet === 'earth'"`

Comment: Thanks both of you guys, it works now !